# REST API, knowing the format for adding an element to an empty list

Tags: rest, hateoas

How do you know the format to post data to a rest based api if there's no documentation?

Should the get for the collection return an example element?

I guess I'm thinking here of HATEOAS, the GET call returns links to POST to but how do you know the format for the POST?

https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

Comment: Ideally, the server should return [415](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13) if the `Content-Type` of your request isn't supported. Although it's not explicitly stated in the RFC, I guess it's allowed (as not explicitly disallowed either) to have the server return the available content types, just like it states for [406](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.6).

But yeah, without a proper API documentation, not sure you can guess exactly which representation of the resource you're supposed to send...

Comment: Is this question intended to be about working with existing REST-like APIs without any documentation, or about best practices on how to build such an API and properly supply that information?

Comment: The latter, building a new API where we can easily find the POST representation without resorting to documentation.

Answer (score 2):

> How do you know the format to post data to a rest based api if there's no documentation?

The server should teach the client how a request should look like. In HTML, i.e., this is done via a Web form that includes all of the elements the server supports. In case of an update the fields may be automatically filled with the current values which can be modified by the user/application. As the form also contains the URI to send the data to, a client simply can trigger a request by invoking the submit button of the form.

For REST APIs a similar approach can and should be taken. Here the server might give the client a hint on the supported media-types (depending whether the media-type received by the client supports such a feature), which could also be looked up via the `OPTIONS` operation that informs the client about the capabilities of the endpoint such as the supported media-types or operations that can be invoked on the endpoint.

> Should the get for the collection return an example element?

If the client is served with a form that explains how a request has to look like, no out-of-band information is actually required here, so this is rather unnecessary.

---

As you've linked the Richardsen Maturity Model (RMM): IMO this model doesn't make much sense in terms of REST. First, there is no REST adherence before level 3 anyway and even with level 3 in place you have no guarantee that you are actually conform to the REST architecture design.

This probably needs some further explanation, I guess. REST is an interaction model and not a protocol. It makes use of the properties that made the Web so successful, such as easy scaling through stateless communication, and reduction of workload due to caching of responses at intermediary servers or distribution of request among load-balanced servers. One of its aims is the decoupling of clients and servers, allowing the latter one to evolve freely without having to fear breaking the former ones. As such, a server should teach a client anything it needs to make educated choices on which "actions" to perform next.

I.e., a server will provide all of the links a client might need including some accompanying link relation names, where the relation names give the URI a named context the client can use to decide whether to invoke it or not. Such names are either standardized by [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xml) or need to be absolute URIs as defined in [RFC 8288 - Web Linking](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288#section-2.1.2), i.e. as [Dublin Core](http://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dc-html/) extensions. This concept allows the server to change URIs of resources at any time. Clients respecting this concept will still be able to process their task while clients parsing and analyzing such URIs might break as a consequence.

According to Fielding

> A REST API should spend almost all of its descriptive effort in defining the media type(s) used for representing resources and driving application state, or in defining extended relation names and/or hypertext-enabled mark-up for existing standard media types. Any effort spent describing what methods to use on what URIs of interest should be entirely defined within the scope of the processing rules for a media type (and, in most cases, already defined by existing media types) ([Source](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven))

In addition to that, Fielding mentioned that clients should not regard [resources to have a certain type](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) but instead negotiate with the server about the supported representation formats understood by both applications via content-type negotiation. A client that is expecting a `http://acmee.com/api/users` endpoint to return a JSON representation with predefined fields may have certain issues if the response either ships with other field names or with other value types or in general with an other structure than expected. This also couples the client directly to the return value of a certain API and thus requires certain out-of-band knowledge. This is i.e. a thing completely missing in the RMM. Therefore, even if you reached level 3 in the RMM you might still fail to respect every constraint Fielding puts in place in order to adhere to the REST architecture style.

Answer (score 1):

### OpenAPI standard

A good way to provide standartized, discoverable information and examples about all the input/output formats of your APIs is the [OpenAPI standard](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification). It's essentially a standard for YAML specification of REST-like API formats with a supporting infrastructure ([Swagger](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/)) that allows easy transformation of that specification to both human-readable documentation, valid examples of input and output data, and also to boilerplate code in many programming languages and frameworks that will send data to/from the documented API.

To get started, the [Swagger page](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/) or the [editor hands-on demo](https://editor.swagger.io/) may be interesting.